# Concern Regarding Hierarchical and Recursive ERD Modeling

Tags: sql, data-modeling, oracle12c

I am learning Oracle Database 12c SQL Data Modeling through the Oracle Academy service. After learning about recursive and hierarchical relationships and how to model them, the following problem was presented:

> “Our company sells products throughout the United States. So we’ve
>   divided the U.S. into four major sales regions: the Northern, Eastern,
>   Southern, and Western regions. Each sales region has a unique region
>   code. Each sales region is then divided into sales districts. For
>   example, the Western region is divided into the Rocky Mountain,
>   Northwest, Pacific Coast, and Pacific districts. Each district has a
>   unique district code. Each district is made up of sales territories.
>   The Rocky Mountain district is composed of three territories:
>   Wyoming-Montana, Colorado, and Utah-New Mexico. The Northwest district
>   is made up of two territories: the Washington and Oregon-Idaho
>   territories. The Pacific Coast district is composed of two
>   territories: the California and Nevada territories. The Pacific
>   District includes the Hawaii territory and the Alaska territory. Each
>   territory has a unique territory code.
>
> Then each sales territory is broken down into sales areas. For
>   example, Colorado is made up of two sales areas: the Front Range and
>   the Western Slope sales areas. Each sales area has a unique sales-area
>   code.
>
> Each salesperson is responsible for one or more sales areas and has a
>   specific sales quota. We also have sales managers who are responsible
>   for one or more sales districts, and sales directors who are
>   responsible for one or more sales regions. Each sales manager is
>   responsible for the territories with his/her districts. We don’t
>   overlap our employees’ responsibilities. Each sales area is always the
>   responsibility of a single salesperson, and our managers' and
>   directors' responsibilities don’t overlap. Sometimes our salespersons,
>   managers, and directors will have special assignments and will not be
>   responsible for sales. We identify all our sales personnel by their
>   employee IDs.”

The following two ERDs were presented as solutions to this problem:

[image: Solution]

I understand that the following two models are also allowed in this situation:
[image: Alternative]

[image: Alternative2]

Similarly, will the following two models also make logical sense?:
[image: Proposal]

[image: Proposal2]

I understand that the models in each of these varies greatly, but are they all logically equal?

Answer (score 0):

> "are they all logically equal?"

In short, no.

All your models introduce managerial relationships between the different types of Employee. That is an unwarranted assumption because there is nothing in the use case description to suggest that is the case. The Employees' responsibilities are all defined in terms of the Divisional breakdown.

I think the models which represent  SALES_DIVISION and SALES_ENTITY as a single hierarchical entities are mistaken. This is logically similar but we have lost business rules. The strict hierarchy of REGION > DISTRICT > TERRITORY > AREA is invisible. Likewise we no longer show the rules mandating which type of Employee is responsible for each type of Area. Also we lose the distinction of which types have a `quota` attribute and which don't.

The purpose of logical data modelling is to visually express the business rules as clearly as possible. This means representing everything in full without adding non-existent rules. When we come to translating the Logical Model into the Physical Model we may choose to merge multiple entities into one table, but I think the ERD should be as expressive as possible.